# render_field do not change "value" attribute

Tags: django, templates

I am using render_field template tag from django-widget-tweaks to change some attributes in the template.

The problem is that the following sentence:

```
{% render_field form.my_field type='my_text' value="" %}
```

Generates this output:

```
<input id="id_my_field" name="field" type="my_text" value="1_-krKwzx3SRSRXuy_TPEX8g">
```

"value" attribute is initialized with the data from the an instance model. Why "type" attribute changes but not "value"? Is there anything I forgot?

Answer (score 3):

This feature was already requested so i suggest reading this comment by the project maintainer, basically it says that changing value in template is not a good idea:

https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks/issues/7#issuecomment-22031104